# Cumulative Sum by Group Using DataFrame - Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My Code:

```
df=temp_df.groupBy('date','id').count()
windowval = (Window.partitionBy('date','id').orderBy('date','id').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
final_df = df.withColumn('cum_sum', F.sum('count').over(windowval)).orderBy('date','id').show()
```

Please correct my code, I believe something wrong in using Window(rangeBetween).

Thanks,

```
DF:
+-------------------+------------------+-----+
|               date|                id|count|
+-------------------+------------------+-----+
|2007-11-04 00:00:00|                 5|    4|
|2007-11-05 00:00:00|                 5|    7|
|2007-11-06 00:00:00|                 5|    3|
|2007-11-06 00:00:00|                 8|    3|
|2007-11-07 00:00:00|                 5|    7|
|2007-11-08 00:00:00|                 5|    2|
|2007-11-08 00:00:00|                 8|    4|
+-------------------+------------------+-----+

Expected output:

+-------------------+------------------+-----+-------+
|               date|                id|count|cum_sum|
+-------------------+------------------+-----+-------+
|2007-11-04 00:00:00|                 5|    4|      4|
|2007-11-05 00:00:00|                 5|    7|     11|
|2007-11-06 00:00:00|                 5|    3|     14|
|2007-11-06 00:00:00|                 8|    3|      3|
|2007-11-07 00:00:00|                 5|    7|     21|
|2007-11-08 00:00:00|                 5|    2|     23|
|2007-11-08 00:00:00|                 8|    4|      7|
+-------------------+------------------+-----+-------+

My Output:

+-------------------+------------------+-----+-------+
|               date|                id|count|cum_sum|
+-------------------+------------------+-----+-------+
|2007-11-04 00:00:00|                 5|    4|      4|
|2007-11-05 00:00:00|                 5|    7|      7|
|2007-11-06 00:00:00|                 5|    3|      3|
|2007-11-06 00:00:00|                 8|    3|      3|
|2007-11-07 00:00:00|                 5|    7|      7|
|2007-11-08 00:00:00|                 5|    2|      2|
|2007-11-08 00:00:00|                 8|    4|      4|
+-------------------+------------------+-----+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your current code to:

```
df = temp_df.groupBy('date', 'id').count()

windowval = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

final_df = df.withColumn('cum_sum', F.sum('count').over(windowval)).orderBy('date', 'id').show()
```

When you partition by id and date, every (`id`, `date`) combination is unique. You need to partition by `id` and `orderBy` `date`

Comment: Thanks @pissall, I tried the same after posting question. It worked. Thanks for your help